# Hibernate - how to load into POJO which is not an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have an entity named father and son1 and son2 who are mapped as collections inside father

Lets say father has a,b,c properties son1 has a,d and son 2 has b,e 
and I have a bean which contains a,b,d,e called MyBean in one query.

Can I use it in a simple query using addEntity(MyBean.class) where my MyBean is not an hibernate entity (POJO)?

---

the POJO is as simple as it gets without annotations

```
class POJO {

Object a,b,d,e;
//get and set's and empty c'tor etc 

}
```

Comment: You lost me, what is the POJO that you are loading?

Comment: What does it mean "mapped as collections"?

Comment: @axtavt meaning: @manyToOne and @OneToMany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the new keyword and create the object in your search query

this only works for jpql

Comment: can you please explain wht you mean using a simple example?

Comment: @yoav.str it is possible to call consructors of any class in jpql queries using the NEW keyword. so basicly queries like `SELECT NEW net.something.fubar(a.hello, SUM(a.world)) FROM fubo a GROUP BY a.hello"`

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use it in a simple query using addEntity(MyBean.class) where my MyBean is not an hibernate entity (POJO)?

I don't believe so.  I believe that hibernate must know about all classes it persists via mappings.